# How to neatly cut off an extreme value in a plot that compresses the rest of a plot?

Tags: matlab

So basically, the graph labeled "Thermal Wind" has an extreme value that compresses the y-values for all the other plots, making it much harder to see any of the individual variations in the other plots. Is there a way to neatly cut off this extreme value? I could just rescale the y limit to a maximum of 40, but then this looks ugly.

[image]

As for the alternative I've tried - it's here:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "ugly"? How *should* it look, in your ideal situation?

Comment: Hmm - I'm not totally sure. I'm turning it in for a school assignment and part of the assignment is graded on presentation. I can try asking the prof but the prof isn't available right now.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend trying to plot it on a log scale.  The function you'll want to consider using is [`semilogx`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html), though for completeness I recommend also reading the help file on [`loglog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loglog.html).

Alternately, you could use [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html) to generate multiple plots, one of which is zoomed into a region of interest.

Comment: Ah yes, I just noticed the negative numbers there and their `log` will be undefined.  One thing you could do, if it's just the presentation you're concerned about is using a `subplot`[1] of the full graph, and another subplot with the region you wanted to accentuate (longitude 40-110 or whatnot).

1. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html

Answer (score 0):

Are the outlier points errors in the data, or do they represent extreme cases?

If they are not valid data, just manually exclude them from the data, plot the graph, and include a text clarification when describing the graph.  If they are valid data, then trimming them would misrepresent the data, which isn't a good thing.

Graphs of data aren't art: their main goal isn't to be pretty; it's to provide a useful visualization of data.  There are some minimum requirements on appearance, however: the axes have to be labeled, the units have to be meaningful, the different curves have to be visually distinct, etc.  As long as your graph has these things, you shouldn't expect to lose marks for presentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches that I use:

1. One approach would be transform the data so it will fill the plot nicely. Make the transform so that it wouldn't touch the range - say -10 to +10. In your case you could choose it so that 100 transforms to +15 and -100 to -15.
   For clarity you need to then also set and label the y ticks appropriately. And for nice style make sure the line changes slope when it goes over the border.
2. I plot the data as is. But set the axis limits say from -10 to +10. Where points lay outside I place upwards and downwards triangles along the border to mark in which direction the "outliers" would be. Obviously this is only good when there aren't too many.